# Is this kind of code is a good coding style in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, styles, coding-style

In koltin it's common to check the input argument to avoid null value, and I often write a lot of codes like this:

```
fun test(text: String?) {
    text ?: return
    // do other things based of text
}
```

Is this a good coding style? Or there is a better one? Thanks for any comment!

Comment: I think that's good, already simple, but it depends on your teams

Comment: If all you're going to do is throw out the value, then why take a `null` at all? If you take `String` (without the question mark) then they can't even call your function with `null`. See [Parse, don't Validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/)

Comment: If you're checking preconditions at the start of the function, [`require()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) (or in this case [`requireNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require-not-null.html)), or [`check()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check.html) (or [`checkNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check-not-null.html)) might be appropriate. Or use a `?:` check when you first use the value.